# count for a collection based on its CURD operation for the last 2 days in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to know the count for the last 2 days happened for a collection based on its CURD operations (UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT) in mongodb.

End result is i need to know how many documents got updated , inserted and deleted and its counts for the last 2 days.

In case I don't have creationDate or updationDate key in my collection then how to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't store updated time. You have to store it yourself.

You can get created date-time using ObjectId

```
ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp() // returns ISO date time
```

***Suggestion:*** It is always a good practice to store createdDate and updateDate with each document in a collection or each row in a table